# Android:Writing data to a file

Tags: android, file

with the below piece of code, I'm able to create a new file called output.txt and i'm able to write data. Problem is this file gets recreated once i close my app and then open my app again. As because i create this in onCreate().

But i would like to have the file created only once and then i would like to append the data there after.

```
private File outputFile = null;
    FileOutputStream fOut = null;
    OutputStreamWriter osw = null;


        @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       ....
      if(outputFile == null)
               outputFile = new  File("/storage/new/output.txt");

             if(osr==null){
               try {
                   osr = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
                   out = new DataOutputStream(osr);
               } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }
             }

             .....
                 try {
                            out.writeBytes(data);
                                out.flush();
                            //out.close();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try setting the [append](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream%28java.io.File,%20boolean%29) flag to true when constructing your FileOutputStream

```
osr = new FileOutputStream(outputFile, true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
FileOutputStream fileOut = openFileOutput(outputFile, MODE_APPEND);
OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fileOut);
osw.writeBytes(data);
osw.flush();
```

Comment: 04-20 21:46:58.750: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(31169): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File /storage/new/output.txt contains a path separator   .........On trying i get a crash in openFileOutput . This is because my outputFile is like "/storage/new/output.txt" , but the function openFileOutput Doesnt take path separators .

Comment: You can probably do something like:

File dir = new File (sdcard.getAbsolutePath() + "/where/you/want/it");
    dir.mkdirs();
    File file = new File(dir, "output.txt");
    FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(file);